# Не понимаю в чем ошибка!

Tags: php, mysqli

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\Crypto\includes\article.php on line 8

код articles.php

```
<?php

$articles = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT title, text, id FROM articles"); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($articles) > 0) {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($articles))
{
echo $row["title"] . "<br>" . $row["text"] . "<br>";
}
```

при том я еще не понимаю, почему скрипт не продолжается!! я ведь использую include, что должно продолжать код.. или это касается только ситуации, когда файл не найден?

Answer (score 1):

Вы скобку забыли, которая закрывает `if`:

```
$articles = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT title, text, id FROM articles");
if (mysqli_num_rows($articles) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($articles)) {
        echo $row["title"] . "<br>" . $row["text"] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Пишите код грамотнее и сразу будете все видеть чего не достает.